# Upside-down numbers differing by 78633

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

When I acquired my Mercedes-Benz car in Germany, the first thing I had to do was to get a license plate. The plate I got had a peculiar number on it. It consisted of 5 different numbers and by mistake when I fixed it upside down the number could be still read, but the value had increased by 78633.
What was my actual license number?

Solve it fast - really fast!

Comment: Solved fast, really fast, as requested :-)

Comment: And that's why number plates are alphanumeric. :p

Comment: I wrote up a brute force program which solves it: www.pastebin.com/59004630 (Lua)

Comment: @warspyking good one buddy :)

Comment: @jatin ty ${}{}$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was originally

> 10968.

The upside-down value is

> 10968+78633=89601.

### Proof of uniqueness

The upside-down number must be at least 10000 bigger than 78633, so its first digit must be 8 or 9 while the first digit of the original number must be 1 or 2. If the first digit or the upside-down number was 9, then the last digit of the original number would have to be 6, so the last digit of the upside-down number would have to be 3+6=9, so the first digit of the original number would have to be 6, which is too large. So **the first digit of the upside-down number, and hence the last digit of the original number, are 8**, which means **the last digit of the upside-down number, and hence the first digit of the original number, are 1**.

Now the original number must be less than 90000-78633=11367, so its second digit must be 0 or 1. But we know it has five distinct digits, so **the second digit of the original number, and hence the fourth digit of the upside-down number, are 0**. By considering the fourth and fifth columns of summation, we now see that **the fourth digit of the original number is 6** and hence **the second digit of the upside-down number is 9**.

Now we have 10?68+78633=89?01, where the two ?'s are each other upside down and therefore must be both 2, both 5, or 9 and 6 respectively (bearing in mind that each number has 5 distinct digits). We can check these 3 cases by hand and verify that 9 and 6 is the only one that works.

QED.

Comment: In afdition to your proof I wrote up a brute force program which proves it: http://pastebin.com/59004630

Comment: It's wrote in Lua btw